# for each loop in Perl

Tags: perl

I want to print each element in an array separating with tab. Here is the code I wrote:

`print FILEOUT $_,"\t" foreach @data;`

I have problem while printing. Extra tab is printing from beginning of the second line.

Can some one help me in this?

Comment: Instead of trying to describe your problem, you should give an example. That way we can see exactly what you mean.

Answer (score 6):

Use [join](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html) instead:

```
print FILEOUT join("\t", @data);
```

Comment: @Prasad Koneru, You should accept the answer if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a "\n" at the end of each element of @array.

```
my @data = ("1\n", "2\n", "3\n");
print join "\t", map { chomp; $_; } @data;
print "\n";
```